# Android upload file on google drive without choosing account option instead of it use specific account

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am creating an android application where requirement to upload any file on google drive, and i am able to upload file on google drive using google drive api. now my problem is i don't want to choose account or Starting the intent prompts the user to select a Google account to sign in with instead of i want to upload file on specific account which i mention on code but i don't know how can do please guide me and provide some sample code for it.
here is my code :

```
protected void signIn() {
    Set<Scope> requiredScopes = new HashSet<>(2);
    requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
    requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
    GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.getGrantedScopes().containsAll(requiredScopes)) {
        initializeDriveClient(signInAccount);
    } else {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                        .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in may fail or be cancelled by the user. For this sample, sign-in is
                // required and is fatal. For apps where sign-in is optional, handle
                // appropriately
                Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in failed.");
                finish();
                return;
            }

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> getAccountTask =
                    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            if (getAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                initializeDriveClient(getAccountTask.getResult());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in failed.");
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```